# Retrieve multiple recipient names from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This is the code:

It works for one recipient.

```
Sub Sendmail()

    Dim olItem As outlook.MailItem
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim iRow As Long

    sPath = "***"
'   // Excel
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'   // Workbook
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath)
'   // Sheet
    Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'   // Create e-mail Item
    Set olItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olItem
        .To = xlSht.Range("A1")
        .CC = xlSht.Range("c1")
        .subject = "test"
        .Display
        .Send
    End With

'   // Close
    xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
'   // Quit
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSht = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

> Query:  As per my requirement the recipients names should be taken
>   from linked Excel sheet.
>
> All the recipients mail address placed in column A of the Excel
>   sheet.
>
> And these values are dynamic, it might contain any number of mail
>   Ids.
>
> Example:
>
> Column A:
>
> yhui@gmail.com  abc@gmail.com  ikj@gmail.com  plo@gmail.com
>
> Here there are 4 values, now the mail should be sent to all these 4
>   recipients at the same time.
>
> So the To field should contain:
>   yhui@gmail.com;abc@gmail.com;ikj@gmail.com;plo@gmail.com
>
> The code should be able to traverse down column A till the last
>   row and concatenate all the values separated by a semicolon (;)

Comment: Use `For` loop.

Comment: Thanks, using for loop mail can be sent to one recipient at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the recipients field:

```
.To = Join(xlApp.Transpose(xlSht.Range("A1", xlSht.Range("A9999").End(xlUp))), ";")
```

Comment: @Sai welcome, glad to help. I noticed that you did not accept any answer to your questions so far. Please think of accepting an answer when it solves your question. Check the gray checkmark on the top-left of the answer to turn it green. Thanks :)

Comment: trust me I never knew it works this way!! thanks again. I have accepted the answer :)

Comment: @Sai No problem :). Thanks for trying, but not yet. You actually "voted up", which is nice, but there's a grey shape in `v` form under the triangle, when you click it, it should turn green to mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: @ A.S.H thanks for the detailed steps, it is accepted now. :)